# Scrapy, Xpath, no results?

Tags: html, python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

URL I'm trying to scrape:

https://www.controller.com/listings/aircraft/for-sale/list?SortOrder=23&scf=False&page=1

I'm new to Scrapy and programming in general but I was still able to scrape a few websites prior to this one.

When I first tried scraping the above URL I kept running into code 403. After some research, I was able to bypass that by downloading the user_agents package for scrapy. The following user agent works:

'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.78 Safari/537.36'

I've experimented with simple Xpath code, such as below, just to make sure that I was getting an output.

```
    def parse(self, response):
        text = response.xpath("//div[@class='mobile-map-select']/text()").extract()
        print(text)
```

After trying many times with different code I still keep getting an empty list as output.

Does anyone have any idea why this keeps happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some websites require you to post headers and cookies. This is called re-engineering the request. Sometimes to access the HTML you need to try mimic the exact request to the server, so this means posting headers and a cookie.

### Re-engineering the HTTP request

Firstly you want to use something like chrometools to look at the request. Right clicking inspect and clicking the network tab, reload the page you want to see the requests for an under the network tab should start to populate all the requests made of the server to load the page up. Here we can find exactly the type of HTTP request needed to load the HTML of the page.

Image1: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3xlx.jpg)

Here we can see the site HTML request on the left side, on the right hand side we have the requests URL is the one we want to make

Image2: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZF5j.jpg)

On the right hand side we now have the request headers and the cookies sent.You create a dictionary headers with keys and values. We can also do the same for the cookies.

We then want to yield a Scrapy request with those headers and those cookies and this mimics the request the server expects.

### Simpler way of Re-engineering the HTTP request

You can copy the curl command of the HTTP request, like seen in the image below.

Image: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKwtn.jpg)

Copying this into [here](https://curl.trillworks.com/), a website that converts it into a python request. This will give you a nice formatted headers/cookies etc. You can then copy the dictionary for headers and cookies.

### Code Example

```
import scrapy

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    allowed_domains = ['https://www.controller.com/listings/aircraft/for-\ 
                      sale/list?SortOrder=23&scf=False&page=1']
    start_urls = ['http://controller.com/']



    cookies = {
    '__cfduid': 'dec92bef19d6ab9ae41ad9a69d3cd1be21594487232',
    'ASP.NET_SessionId': '5cjpkvyh5sjstdhd12eglk5b',
    'USERID': '170264603',
    'TRACKING': 'SessionStarted=1&GUID=9a1b8738f0b94ccb943e2f865c9a2199&UserReferrer=https%3a%2f%2fwww.controller.com%2flistings%2faircraft%2ffor-sale%2flist%3fSortOrder%3d23%26scf%3dFalse%26page%3d1',
    'TopPopup-Cookie_11': 'Unit=available&Retry=2020-07-12T17:07:15.9365191Z',
    '__RequestVerificationToken': 'AJ3z0d7OpPyY49AuIT-JJCxLZ5-JjJ0Fwf20lAdSLIRmrowO1Kwv-Cy3Bo7AHkkyODF0Sg2',
    'BIGipServerwww.controller.com_http_pool': '1065461952.20480.0000',
    'UserSettingsSession': 'Geo=GB%7cUnited+Kingdom%7cEdinburgh%7cEdinburgh%7cEH11%7c55.9335%7c-3.254%7c0%7c0%7c%7c&screen-size-set=True',
    'UserSettings': 'currency-preference=USD&override-currency=True&onelinelistings=False&unit-preference=imperial&override-unit=True&DefaultMap=&thumbnailphotos=True&screen-height=912&screen-width=1368&image-height=480&image-width=639',
    'reese84': '3:vi2UoeO7DhA7Vp0/IEXo+Q==:0C/8X3VRY0DMDTzIz4ceLFK5QsFhd0l+hlqDe5lhpnON5Y0j4IuQ/kfec8PKCiE6bqdpfPB3/8EK0gk4yh43mSJnfJS3Xwmzm9Tl9YyEMnRrZ2+xNjWQHWqZydQVUlfJlQwPsBz/6/dF7I21OZq4KnSk8SbfVHOQM5J7NpDJIAWggoeLQmgbD1v/3+zePS13n71Xnkz3XAei43S/RI/U74wuRlYkO204yb/Me5hngUW/8Reqguk3iXdNN9H4GAjKdZKmYxsVVGtN/huigZQ4+05I2rHk+nV3zirdYAdZJ10qLw+2RpBAQ30S4YwBulz9wEODkSbUhJGTSh9dUK/i3grtrHIHfNDgyJqrI0Ydif1gDOf77qBz35gQQO1rRMvXj3p5VB7/FnOa+2UVlL8WG79AFSo1t7NEuINjGmKUaHc=:hH59BHHAflKbvFUyM1poFPhO9puxXq5tjYw7E9wzA78=',
    'KeepUserOnSite': 'True',
    'CurrentLatitude': '55.902207999999995',
    'CurrentLongitude': '-3.3292287999999997',
}

     headers = {
         'authority': 'www.controller.com',
         'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
         'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
         'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36',
         'accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,
             image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed- 
             exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
         'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
         'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
         'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
         'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
         'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
           }

     def start_requests(self):
         url = 'https://www.controller.com/listings/aircraft/for-sale/list? \
                SortOrder=23&scf=False&page=1'
         yield scrapy.Request(url=url,headers=self.headers,
              cookies=self.cookies,callback=self.parse)

     def parse(self,response):
         response.text
```

The Request method accepts an url, because we have defined headers outside the start_request function we have to use self.headers and self.cookies to get access to it. We then want to send the response to the function parse and we do that by specifying a callback. The `start_request` function can be used to process URLs before the parse function. Scrapy automatically passes the response normally when we setup a spider to parse.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I really appreciate you taking the time to respond in such a thoughtful way. Being a beginner, this definitely helps in understanding what re-engineering the request is and how it works. I followed the steps you provided to make sure I was able to get the same output as you and the code works :) Thanks very much again!

Comment: I think you meant `start_requests()` instead of `start_request()`. Moreover, `start_requests(self)` doesn't take any parameter other than self, right @AaronS?

Comment: After changing to 'start_requests()' and taking out the 'response' parameter from the start_requests function I get an error when running the scrapy: `2020-07-13 13:01:46 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies] WARNING: Invalid cookie found in request <GET https://www.controller.com/listings/aircraft/for-s
ale/list?SortOrder=23&scf=False&page=1>: {'name': 'CurrentLongitude', 'value': ''} ('value' is missing)
`  whereas prior to making this change I actually was getting the correct output?

Comment: I suspect the cookie inputted has expired and that is why you're getting the error message. It depends on whether you're wanting to run this spider more than once. If it's just a once off scrape then my answer above will be fine. If it's for several scrapes or routine scraping, you will need grab the cookies for each individual time you do a request. There are several ways to do that, check out the cookeis middleware in the scrapy docs or you could use selenium/splash to render the cookies and pass that seperate in a request.

Comment: @AaronS this dont work for me it give 405 Method not allowed can you help me with that.

Comment: @Arty Neeed help with this anyone?